# Wordpress number permalinks instead of title words

Tags: wordpress

I configured my wordpress permalinks to be `year/month/postname` format, and updated my `.htaccess` file with code that WP provided me.

Now, when I write post title, and click out of title box to get permalink, instead of `blog.com/2012/10/my-blog-title` I get `blog.com/2012/10/12345` where 12345 is always a 5-digit number that is being shown at random, I guess?

How can I get permalink with post title?

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /my_blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I edited post and added `.htaccess` code!

Comment: try disabling plugins, switch permalinks off/on agian check again. Check each plugin this way. And lastly the theme.

Comment: Disable plugins, switch to a default theme. Can you also post a screenshot of your Settings > Permalinks page? Thanks!

Comment: @kovshenin here's the image http://s13.postimage.org/ts95js6d3/Screen_shot_2012_10_10_at_12_09_00.png

Comment: Looks fine. Not entirely sure what the problem might be. Have you disabled plugins and reverted theme? Can you edit the permalink slug after the post has been saved?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with reverting theme, disabling/enabling plugins, and nothing. @kovshenin Yes I can edit permalink slug afterwards.

Comment: Err, it's *disabling* plugins, not disabling/enabling :) However, sounds like everything is working well. The numeric permalink is being assigned when your post has no title. If you give it a title and save draft you should see the proper post slug generated from the title.